# ¿cómo eliminar con Ajax y Laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel

Necesito eliminar una columna usando Ajax y Laravel hasta el momento tengo lo siguiente pero no me funciona.

view()

```
<button id="eliminarArticulo" ruta = "{{URL::to('auto/eliminarArticulo')}}" onclick="eliminarArticulo({{$detalle_modelo->idetalleModelo}})" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```

js(ajax)

```
   <script>

        function  eliminarArticulo(id) {

             var ruta = $('#eliminarArticulo').attr('ruta');
             var url = ruta+"/"+id;

          //   alert(url)

            $.post({
                url: url,
                data: {id:id},
                dataType: 'json',
                success : function (res) {
                   // console.log(res);
                }
            });

        }

</script>
```

Ruta

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auto'], function(){
    Route::get('crear', 'AutoController@crear')->name('auto.crear');
  Route::post('registrar', 'AutoController@registrar')->name('auto.registrar');
    Route::get('listar', 'AutoController@listar')->name('auto.listar');
    Route::get('editar/{cod}', 'AutoController@editar')->name('auto.editar');
    Route::post('actualizar', 'AutoController@actualizar')->name('auto.actualizar');
    Route::get('ver/{cod}', 'AutoController@ver')->name('auto.ver');
    Route::post('guardarArticulo', 'AutoController@guardarArticulo')->name('auto.guardarArticulo');
    Route::get('editarArticulo/{cod}', 'AutoController@editarArticulo')->name('auto.editarArticulo');
    Route::post('actualizarArticulo', 'AutoController@actualizarArticulo')->name('auto.actualizarArticulo');
    Route::post('ActualizarEstadoAuto/{cod}', 'AutoController@ActualizarEstadoAuto')->name('auto.ActualizarEstadoAuto');
    Route::post('eliminarArticulo/{cod}', 'AutoController@eliminarArticulo')->name('auto.eliminarArticulo');

});
```

controlador

```
 public function eliminarArticulo(Request $request){

      return $request;
}
```

Comment: ¿Te retorna el id correcto la función eliminarArticulo?

Answer (score 1):

Bueno deberia de ser así:

**View**

```
<button id="eliminarArticulo" onclick="eliminarArticulo({{$detalle_modelo->idetalleModelo}})" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```

**js**

```
function eliminarArticulo(id) {
 $.ajax({
    url: 'url' + id,
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
        // bla bla
    }
 });
```

}

**Controller**

```
public function eliminarArticulo($id) {
  // delete
  $articulo = Articulo::find($id);
  $articulo->delete();

  return response()->json([
    'message' => 'Articulo Eliminado'
  ]);    
}
```